# Freeze when moving mouse to bottom right corner of screen since Ati Catalyst 11.5

Tags: 11.04, drivers, ati

Today i upgraded from ATI Catalyst 11.4 beta to 11.5. When i move my mouse to the bottom right corner of the screen the system becomes unresponsive for ~1 second. Everywhere else is fine.

I have no idea what might cause this issue. Thanks for help!

**Update:**

Catalyst 11.6 did not fix that bug. The system still freezes for ~1 second when the mouse cursor is moved to the bottom right corner of the screen.

**Update 2:**

Finally Catalyst 11.7 is released. Did it fix the bug? No, it's still present. One "workaround" (i won't call it fix, because it has side effects) is to enable the SWCursor in the xorg.conf which causes some flickering of the cursor but the system wont freeze anymore.

**Summary:**

[Bug Report in AMD Bugzilla](http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=141)

- Catalyst 11.4: works
- Catalyst 11.5: freeze when moving mouse to bottom right corner of screen
- Catalyst 11.6: freeze when moving mouse to bottom right corner of screen
- Catalyst 11.7: freeze when moving mouse to bottom right corner of screen
- Catalyst 11.8: works again :)

Workaround:

add

```
Option "SWCursor" "true"
```

to xorg.conf

Comment: I encountered the same problem upon installing Catalyst 11.5. I'm running a Radeon HD 5770 on an ASUS M4A89TD PRO/USB3. I ended up fixing the mouse problem by reinstalling Catalyst 11.4.

Comment: I also reinstalled 11.4. Apperantly this bug is not Ubuntu specific and even occurs on Windows. ATI granted Windows-Users a Hotfix, looks like we have to wait for 11.6 and hope its fixed in our Version too.

Comment: Slowly but surely this is making me angry. Finally Catalyst 11.6 was released and still the bug remains although they say it's fixed in the changelog (at least for Windows 7).

Comment: 11.7 is out - has anyone tried yet if it fixes this issue?

Comment: See something is up with either the driver or the card. I know when I made my hackintosh, I had to edit a file to make it say HWCursor = False so, its something weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newly released ATI Catalyst 11.8 finally fixes the bug!

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that ATI Catalyst 11.7b fixes the mouse freeze bug.

It also fixes the "external HDMI monitor" bug.

Tested on Ubuntu 11.04 64-Bit with 5x and 6x cards.

Install it and be happy!!!

Comment: Is 11.7b the default driver from the ATI download page or did you get it from another source?

Comment: wow - someone showed me the freeze bug with 11.7. Please check the file length of your "fglrx_8.872-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb" file. Is it  35941172 Bytes (no bug) or 35938302 Bytes (mouse freeze)?????

Comment: where did you download the driver? I always check the amd page: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Comment: definately not working for me..

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with Ubuntu 10.04 64bits / Radeon 6450 / Catalyst 11.7

I downgrade to 11.4 and the bug disapears.

Answer (score 0):

Did anyone else try this suggestion from the Unofficial ATI wiki yet?

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Troubleshooting#Sticky_mouse_cursor

I haven't found any evidence of any one else having solved the problem this way, and I can't try it myself as I think that for now I will stick to the open source drivers from the xorg-edgers PPA. At least until the problem is fixed in fglrx.

Comment: Not working. Besides Xorg.log says: `"dri" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.` I have no idea why that's in the wiki.